# Multiple Angular 4 Areas in .NET Core 2 Project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, asp.net-core-2.0, area

I would like to have multiple Areas in my project that do share the same session. 
For instance I would like my main Area to be an SPA for Promoting my product, i would like a shop area with a separate SPA to sell stuff and i would like to have a third SPA where the users can manage their products.

I have tried setting this up, but it seems that because of the angular router it goes to the right controller, but the right spa is not being loaded.

[image]

This is my folder structure.

I think it must have something to do with the views, because my index.cshtml looks like this:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<app asp-area="App" asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>

<script src="~/dist/vendor.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/dist/main-client.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
}
```

i tried googling, but with no avail.
Can anyone explain how to set my index to load the right SPA?

Comment: Did you ever find anything out about this? Very interested in how you handled it.